# What's a good name for this technology?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction

I saw on Rick and Morty last night, Rick has a bubble gun which he uses to encase each of his grandchildren in a bubble. I really like this idea for capturing animals in the wild. You can encase them in a bubble so they are easier to transport. The bubbles surface might have a mild electric charge to keep them from moving. What would a good sci-fiesque name for this type of gun?

Comment: The mapping of words to things is relatively arbitrary at the best of times. If the only criteria for the name is that it is "sci-fiesque" then this question is entirely too opinion based for this site.

Comment: Ok. I guess you're right. I just didn't want to rip off Rick and Morty, even though Rick would do it himself ;)

Comment: Strangely enough calling it a bubble-gun sounds science-fictional enough. Besides it's generic enough for this type of weapon. It's comparable to the blaster and the stunner. generic science-fictional technology and names for them appear all over the shop. Don't be afraid to use them too.  Although calling it something like the Immobilizer does have appeal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POKE-gun (pokeballs)

Encapsulation (encapsulator)

Bubblification

the ketchum-100

Comment: since it is a scifi-gun, something with "-aser" - 
bubblaser, gumaser ..?